# How to make the picture in the center of this? (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I can't make the picture in the center of this, I can do with the button and text but not the picture. Here is my code and the webpage. https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/741986644542095360/873178308718776340/unknown.png?width=1151&height=356

```
      <v-main>
        <v-container fill-height fluid>
          <v-row>
            <v-col ref="vcol" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" cols="3">
              <v-card class="mb-2" height="200" width="200">
              
                <v-row>
                  <v-col class="shrink">
                    
                    <v-img
                      :src="'http://localhost:1337' + item.picture.url"
                      max-height="200"
                      max-width="200"
                      class="ml-3"
                    ></v-img>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
                
              </v-card>
          

              <div class="center">
                <br />
                <label for="name"
                  >Name:
                  <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                </label>
                <br />
                <label for="points"
                  >Points:
                  <td>{{ item.points }}</td></label
                >
                <br />
                <label for="amount"
                  >Amount:
                  <td>{{ item.amount }}</td>
                </label>
              </div>

              <br />
              <div class="center">
              <v-btn @click="redeemReward(item)" :disabled="item.amount === 0">Redeem Reward</v-btn>
              </div>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
```

Comment: You can use `class="mx-auto" `.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  **aspect-ratio="1"** to *v-img*. I have a question why use extra *v-row* and *v-col* inside *v-card*?
please pay attention to this code

```
<div id="app">
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" cols="3">
              <v-card class="mb-2" height="200" width="200">     
                    <v-img
                      :src="item.url"
                      max-height="200"
                      max-width="200"
                      aspect-ratio="1"
                      class="ml-3"
                      contain
                    ></v-img>
              </v-card>
              <div class="center">
                <br />
                <label for="name"
                  >Name:
                  <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                </label>
                <br />
                <label for="points"
                  >Points:
                  <td>{{ item.points }}</td></label
                >
                <br />
                <label for="amount"
                  >Amount:
                  <td>{{ item.amount }}</td>
                </label>
              </div>

              <br />
              <div class="center">
   
              </div>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
</div>
```

script:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          id:1,
         url:'https://picsum.photos/200/700',
          name:'akbar',
          amount:200,
          points:2,
          text: "a"
        },
        {
          id:2,
         url:'https://picsum.photos/700/400',
          name:'akbar',
          amount:200,
          points:2,
          text: "b"
        },
        {
          id:3,
          url:'https://picsum.photos/200/400',
          name:'akbar',
          amount:200,
          points:2,
          text: "c"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```